# Running Service in Background like whatsapp

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-notifications, intentservice, android-intentservice

I don't know why this code does not works,  I am trying to Background Service like whatsapp which runs forever and checks for notification.

But that is not working, I dont know where i am doing wrong.

1. I have added service in android manifest

`<receiver android:name=".Notifications">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIMEZONE_CHANGED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIME_SET" />
                <action android:name="com.application.Notifications" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:name=".BackgroundWorker"></service>`

2. I created three classes "BackgroundWorker extends IntentService"

`public BackgroundWorker() {
        super("androidservice");
    }

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {



    Log.v("BackgroundWorker:","working" );

    //user method
    createNotification(getApplicationContext(),"BackgroundWorker");
}`
```

2. class 'Notifications extends BroadcastReceiver'

```
@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {

    Log.d("BroadcastReceiver","onReceive");

    Intent t = new Intent(context,BackgroundWorker.class);
    context.startService(t);

}
```

3. I created third class 
` Long alertTime = new GregorianCalendar().getTimeInMillis() + 1*1000;

```
    Intent notifications = new Intent(this,Notifications.class);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,alertTime,1*1000,PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,
            1,
            notifications,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));

    Log.d("AlarmManager",alarmManager.toString());`
```

I don't know where i am doing wrong.

**Although i have set 1 second for Repeatition but still i get notification in interval of 5 min **

**And i have checked the android service, my app is not running**
please help me out...

`06-16 10:25:21.537 9833-9833/ D/BroadcastReceiver: onReceive
06-16 10:25:21.614 9833-12666/D/BroadcastReceiver: createNotification
06-16 10:30:21.245 9833-9833/ D/BroadcastReceiver: onReceive
06-16 10:30:21.376 9833-15746/r D/BroadcastReceiver: createNotification
06-16 10:35:21.209 9833-9833/ D/BroadcastReceiver: onReceive
06-16 10:35:21.283 9833-18645/ D/BroadcastReceiver: createNotification
06-16 10:40:21.179 9833-9833/ D/BroadcastReceiver: onReceive
06-16 10:40:21.224 9833-21479/ D/BroadcastReceiver: createNotification
06-16 10:45:21.188 9833-9833/ D/BroadcastReceiver: onReceive
06-16 10:45:21.246 9833-24302/ D/BroadcastReceiver: createNotification`

Comment: did u find any solution to it

Comment: the problem was Xiaomi Device. Services are better suited for this purpose

Comment: Can you share the code please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IntentService stops itself after the code in onHandleIntent() has executed. You need to extend a normal Service and handle threading by yourself. If you don't call stopSelf, the service will continue to run (probably until the system kills it).